# Spinner returns null

Tags: java, android, sqlite, api, metadata

The `countryCodeSpinner` shows up as `null` in following code snippet.

```
countryCodeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_country);
countryCodeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                selectedCountryCode = (Long) selectedItemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name).getTag();

            }
```

Comment: The code is all over the place, please correct it. And add some context to the code.

Comment: Maybe there is no resource with R.id.spinner_country in your layout.
Please ensure that you've selected the correct layout

Comment: @avinash tiwari refere [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) befor asking questions

Comment: add your logcat and where you set the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have placed 'setContentView()' method before initializing spinner. Also it can be possible that the resource id is different from which you are using in the same layout file.

Comment: tnx pavan , i got it basically the problem was not placed 'setContentView()' method before initializing spinner